# In Linux, is there a way to target/query a window to fetch it's process info?

Tags: linux

There's feature in Process Explorer for Windows where you can *target* a window...

[image: PS target icon]

...by dragging the target icon to a window to find that window's process:

[image: PS target dragged]

This then highlights the process row in the list:

[image: PS row highlight]

This way, you can tell exactly what process owns a particular window or dialog.

Is there a way to do this in Linux?

Perhaps if there is no graphical solution, is there a more technical command-line based solution? e.g. List windows by title, grep, and show associated processes.

Answer (score 1):

With `xprop` (e.g. clicking on `xeyes`):

[image]

Comment: Does anything work with Wayland? ;-)

Comment: To get the PID: `xprop | grep PID`